# Avoid repeated entries from same user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to build an auction site. I've set up my placebid view and I'm quite happy with how it functions but the problem is the same user is able to bid on the same listing multiple times. This is okay but instead of it being stored in the database as several separate bids all by the same user, I want the initial bid to be updated or initial bid removed and new bid created.

I did try UniqueConstraint and added to my Bid model (fields: bidder and bid_input) but it made no difference plus when I deleted it from my Bid model and makemigrations there were no changes detected so it seems the database was dismissing it anyway.

I tried to do a .filter().exists() check before saving the form in my placebid view and now the form lets me place an initial bid but when I do a second bid it returns a Page Not Found error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/listing/3/bid
Raised by:  auctions.views.placebid
No Bid matches the given query.
```

**This is my functional views.py with no form validation checking:**

```
def placebid(request, id):
    listing_bid = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=id)
    highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max'] or Decimal('0')
    currentHighest = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max']
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        bidform = BidForm(request.POST)
        if bidform.is_valid() and highest_bid == 0:
            bid_placed = bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input']
            if bid_placed <= listing.start_price:
                messages.error(request, 'Make sure your bid is greater than the start price')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
            else:
                newbid = bidform.save(commit=False)
                newbid.bidder = request.user
                newbid.bid_input = bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input']
                newbid.bid_item = listing_bid
                newbid.time = timezone.now()
                newbid.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Bid placed succesfully')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
        if bidform.is_valid() and highest_bid > 0:
            bid_placed = bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input']
            if bid_placed <= highest_bid:
                messages.error(request, 'Make sure your bid is greater than the current highest bid')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
            else:
                newbid = bidform.save(commit=False)
                newbid.bidder = request.user
                newbid.bid_input = bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input']
                newbid.bid_item = listing_bid
                newbid.time = timezone.now()
                newbid.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Bid placed succesfully')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
    else:
        bidform = BidForm()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
```

**This is the .filter().exists() checking that I added:**

```
                bid = get_object_or_404(Bid, id=id)
                if bid.bid_input.filter(bidder=request.user.id).exists():
                    bid.bid_input.remove(request.user)
                    newbid = bidform.save(commit=False)
                    newbid.bidder = request.user
                    newbid.bid_input = bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input']
                    newbid.bid_item = listing_bid
                    newbid.time = timezone.now()
                    newbid.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Bid placed succesfully')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
                else:
                    newbid = bidform.save(commit=False)
                    newbid.bidder = request.user
                    newbid.bid_input = bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input']
                    newbid.bid_item = listing_bid
                    newbid.time = timezone.now()
                    newbid.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Bid placed succesfully')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
```

**Bid model**

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bidders")
    bid_item = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bid_items", default=None)
    bid_input = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bidder}, bid amount: {self.bid_input}"
```

**Edited to add BidForm:**

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ["bid_input"]
        labels = {"bid_input": ""}
        widgets = {
            "bid_input": forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter bid (£)'})
        }
```

Comment: show your BidForm too

Comment: I've now added BidForm to my question

Answer (score 0):

firsrt of all what i don't like in your view is that you form validation distributed between form and view. At first you check that form `is_valid` and then add other validation. I would move this validation into `ModelForm`
to do this you need to provide to form all needed data such as `form_bidder`, `hidhest_bid`, `bid_item`

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ["bid_input"]
        labels = {"bid_input": ""}
        widgets = {
            "bid_input": forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter bid (£)'})
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form_bidder = kwargs.pop("form_bidder")
        self.highest_bid = kwargs.pop("hidhest_bid")
        self.bid_item = kwargs.pop("bid_item")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_bid(self):
        bid_input = self.cleaned_data.get("bid_input")
        if bid_input and self.highest_bid == 0 and bid_input < self.bid_item.start_price:
            self.add_errror("bid_input", "Make sure your bid is greater than the start price")
        if bid_input and self.highest_bid > 0 and bid_input < self.highest_bid:
            self.add_errror("bid_input", "Make sure your bid is greater than the current highest bid")
        return bid_input

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.bidder = self.form_bidder
        self.instance.bid_item = self.bid_item
        self.instance.time = timezone.now()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

1. in `placebid` view you have `listing` and `listing_bid` they should be the same, why do you need both of them? if you want to throw an exception when object is not found then keep `listing` otherwise keep `listing_bid`
2. to update data that user entered eaerlier instead of creating new, you need to provide `instance` attribute to `modelform` which contains data, user entered before.

```
def placebid(request, id):
    highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max'] or Decimal('0')
    currentHighest = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max']
    # listing_bid = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=id)
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=id) 
    form_instance = Bid.objects.filter(bidder=request.user, bid_item=listing).first() 

    if request.method == "POST":
        bidform = BidForm(
            request.POST, 
            instance=form_instance, 
            form_bidder=request.user, 
            hidhest_bid=highest_bid,
            bid_item = listing,
            )
        if bidform.is_valid():
            newbid = bidform.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Bid placed succesfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
        else:
            for error in bidform.errors:
                messages.error(request, str(error))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
    else:        
        bidform = BidForm(
            instance=form_instance, 
            form_bidder=request.user, 
            hidhest_bid=highest_bid,
            bid_item = listing,
        )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to apply your changes to my forms.py and views.py but I'm getting key errors at self.form_bidder=kwargs.pop("form_bidder") and I'm not sure why

Comment: my mistake, changed answer in `else` case. replaced `bidform = BidForm()`